# node.js socket.io instead of AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, socket.io

This question is regarding improving speed and minimizing idle time....

One of my page requires 2 database calls. first db call is about user data which is fast operation. second db call is an aggregation pipeline call which takes more time to finish.

So I just render the page once the first db call is complete. Then use AJAX call to perform second db op and display it on the page.

Question - I know how socket.io works, but is it possible to do the following:

1. Browser requests page
2. Server computes db call #1 and sends the response
3. Server continues to compute db call#2 and waits for browser to connect via socket.io
4. Browser renders page from step #2 and connects to browser using socket.io
5. Server sends results of db call#2 to browser.

What I achieve is #3 executes while #4 is executed hence minimizing server idle time and optimizing user experience.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: well it can be done with node. but i suspect if it would be a good practice!

Comment: I don't see why you need a webSocket for any of this.  The server can do everything it was going to do without a webSocket.  The client can just render the first page it gets and then send an ajax request to get the second piece form the server.  The server can start building the second piece the moment the very first page request comes in just like in your webSocket scenario, except there is no need for a webSocket, nor does it provide any advantage here either.

Comment: @jfriend00 How would you send the results of db call#2 which is already computed back to the AJAX call?

Comment: You cache it in a short term cache on the server (e.g. intended to only last for minutes) and when the client ajax call comes in, you spew the cached result back to the client as the result of that ajax call.  You'd have this same issue with the webSocket too because the socket wouldn't come in any sooner than the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00. will it be a good practice if the way OP wants to achieve..

Comment: A websocket is very useful for continued communication between client and server, especially if you want to push info from server to client at any given time.  But, to retrieve one piece of information, a webSocket is inefficient, overkill and offers no advantages over an Ajax call.  It has more setup cost than a simple ajax call because it starts with an ajax call and then does more communication to switch to a webSocket and then you'd send the message and then the client would close the webSocket.  An Ajax call is just request/response.  Much more streamlined- what http was built for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do what you've proposed with socket.io, but I don't see any reason why you would do it that way because an ajax call instead of the webSocket could offer the same performance streamlining, but be more efficient.  Here's how it would work:

1. Browser requests page
2. Server computes db call #1 and sends the response
3. Server continues to compute db call#2
4. When server finishes with db call#2, the result is cached temporarily for a particular client.
5. Meanwhile, browser gets first page HTML and renders that
6. Web page then starts an Ajax call to request the results of call #2
7. Server returns previously cached result as Ajax response and then clears cache
8. Client receives Ajax response and processes it

Because there's no need to have a continuously connected client and server and because a simple Ajax request/response is more efficient than creating a webSocket, it seems to me like the Ajax call is more efficient than setting up a webSocket just for one piece of data.

But, your webSocket mechanism you outlined certainly could work (in browsers that support webSockets).